# How to update table data with array from PHP function

Tags: php, function

I'm building a simple budgeting app, and I'm trying to filter a table of results based upon a dropdown menu with the months of the year in it.  When the page loads it fires off a php function that gets all the budget categories in the current month, and that's working fine.  What I want to do is be able to select a different month from the dropdown menu and then update the table with only items from that month.

**How could I update the table with only the selected month's data?**

Here's my AJAX call that will successfully alert the array of filtered results, but that's about as far as I know how to get.  I don't know how to take the AJAX response and feed it into the table.

```
function filterCategory() {
var cur_month = $('#month option:selected').attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/functions.php', 
        data: {action: "filter_categories", cur_month:cur_month},
        success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                }
    });
};
```

here's my PHP functions, one for getting the initial list of income and expense categories:

```
function get_income_cat() {
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
$cur_month = date('m');
try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE is_income = '1' AND     month ='" . $cur_month . "' ORDER BY cat_name ASC;");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ("ERROR: Data could not be retrieved from the database." . $e);
    exit;
}
$income = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $income;
};

function get_expense_cat() {
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
$cur_month = date('m');
try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE is_income = '0' AND     
month ='" . $cur_month . "' ORDER BY cat_name ASC;");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ("ERROR: Data could not be retrieved from the database." . $e);
    exit;
}
$expense = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $expense;
};
```

and here's my main php/html code:

```
<?php foreach($income as $key=>$value) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td id="<?php echo $value['cat_id_PK']; ?>"><?php echo $value['cat_name']; ?></td>
              <td id="<?php echo $value['cat_id_PK']; ?>">&#36;<?php echo $value['cat_amount']; ?></td>
            </tr>
           <?php }; ?>

<?php foreach($expense as $key=>$value) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td id="<?php echo $value['cat_id_PK']; ?>"><?php echo $value['cat_name']; ?></td>
              <td id="<?php echo $value['cat_id_PK']; ?>">&#36;<?php echo $value['cat_amount']; ?></td>
            </tr>
           <?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the response alerted to you? I do not see the function `filterCategory()` being called in the code provided. I assume you are using an onchange event to initiate the AJAX call.

Inside the success function you must take the response and instead of alerting it you must place it within the document as follows:

```
$('#the_target').html(response);
```

Comment: I'm using the onchange event to fire off filterCategory().  So I can just insert the response into my html table?  Won't that just add it to the existing information, or will it overwrite it?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve (what type of response you are building) will answer how you handle it in Javascript. Since you are using the jQuery library you have made life easy on yourself. There are functions to handle both. I suggest taking a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ and check html vs append vs appendTo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something like JSON to encode the PHP data for the AJAX request (see [php:json_encode](http://php.net/json-encode). Then it becomes a fairly trivial operation. You can see the bare bones of the concept at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr7ac/), although I'm not even going to **pretend** that I'm using any best-practices there - this is just intended as a VERY rough sketch.

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    $.get('http://examples.joeysmith.com/gistfile3.txt', 
        function(data) {
            var table = $('#table tr:last');
            table.html('');
            console.log(table);
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var recType in json) {

                for(var rec in json[recType]) {
                    td = json[recType][rec];
                    table.after('<tr>'
                               +'<td id="'+td.cat_id_PK+'">'+td.cat_name+'</td>'
                               +'<td>'+td.cat_amount+'</td>'
                               +'</tr>');
                }
            }
        }
    )
});
```